# Antiforgery.Validate Method error in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Im trying to validate an Antiforgery token in my ASP.NET MVC3 application. My code is as follows:

```
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            string cookieToken = "";
            string formToken = "";

            IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
            if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
            {
                string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                    formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                }
            }
            //Validation
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
        }
```

The function Antiforgery.Validate does not seem to work and shows the following error:

```
The best overloaded method match for System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(System.Web.HttpContextBase, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

However, on MSDN the function exists as one of the overloaded ones. Is this a reference error? I am using the System.Web.Helpers namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test with a dummy project told me that **ASP.NET MVC3** does **NOT** have a method `AntiForgery.Validate(string, string)`. It only has:

1. `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate()`
2. `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(System.Web.HttpContextBase, string)`

You might want to upgrade your project or change:

```
AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
```

to

```
AntiForgery.Validate(this.HttpContext, formToken); // I hope that the correct httpcontext, you might wanna check though.
```